# Automation of web application with Java Swing buttons

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I have a web application in which some buttons are made by Java Swing.  I am unable to see the element or DOM of the buttons.  How do I find the elements?  I am automating the application using Selenium.

Comment: Do you mean a Java Applet embedded on a webpage?  Java Swing buttons will not be part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scripting your automation test using selenium you want be able to identity these buttons using selenium, But you can use an another API which has the ability of identifying the location of these buttons then use selenium web driver perform related actions.
Sikuli is one recommendation with the assumption that the buttons has text or visual uniqueness.
You can follow this [tutorial](https://testingtoolsandtechniques.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/using-sikuli-api-with-selenium-web-driver-for-image-based-recognition/) for more information.

Comment: Tq u Kachiex... but sikuli depends on Image Resolution.. Is there any other tool to automate..

Answer (score 0):

If there is SWING in HTML, I think you have Java Applet. In your Applet write below function:

```
clickButton(String name)
```

Implement above and find button in Java and call `doClick`.

You can use `<applet-name>.clickButton(<button-name>)` from JavaScript and so Selenium.